# How can I remove a certain view stored in an ArrayList<EditText> on a click of a button?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-edittext

So I'm creating an activity where users can create a poll.

**I have:**

1- Dynamically-added EditTexts

2- A `List<EditText> allEds = new ArrayList<>();` that holds all the EditText views.

3- also dynamically attaching **ImageButtons** '❌' that work as a **deletion tool** attached on each and every **EditText**.

**I simply want to:**

Detect which **EditText view** the user deletes, in order to **remove** it synchronically from the **allEds List**.

In other words, when a user clicks on a **deletion button** attached to an **EditText** (besides deleting both views which I successfully did) I want to know which **deletion button** on which **EditText** was clicked and remove its whole **value** from the **ArrayList**.

Help me please.

Comment: Isn't the button id enough?

Comment: I tried this but the thing is how will I remove the same EditText from the ArrayList as there is no connection between the button id and the array serialization. So I thought why not use a counter++, it succeeded but I couldn't make it accurate, sometimes it throws an error (invalid index #, array size#), other times it removes the wrong value.

Comment: Please show us the code of your attempt.  We can't tell why there is "no connection " without seeing your code.  Likewise we cannot explain the source of the errors if we can't see the code that generates them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `EditText` tag attribute by using `view.setTag()` method: So that each couple of Button & `EdiText` should have the same tag.

Then are a couple of options to link that to the list:

**First one:**

Make the tag value as an integer value that equals to the `EditText` index in the list: And remove it directly on the button click:

```
button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    int buttonTag = (int) v.getTag();
    allEds.remove(buttonTag);
});
```

**Second one:**

Handling indexes in the first option can be a cumbersome, so you can just look for the intended tag by iterating over the list:

```
button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    String buttonTag = (String) v.getTag();

    for(EditText editText: allEds) {
        String edtitextTag = (String) editText.getTag();
        if (buttonTag.equals(edtitextTag)) {
            // remove EditText
            allEds.remove(editText);
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain what EditText editText : allEds means?

Comment: @MostafaSalem it is a forEach loop in java.. that means for each element (editText) in the list of elements (allEds) .. do the following... You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work) for more info